# am I over thinking this?

Tags: c

I was presented with the following homework problem:

Consider the following C program segment. Rewrite it using no goto's or breaks.

```
j = -3;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    switch (j + 2) {
        case 3:
        case 2: j--;
        break;
        case 0: j += 2; break;
        default: j = 0;
    }
    if (j > 0) break;
    j = 3 - i;
}
```

After studying this for a few minutes, I came to the conclusion that the code segment would simply produce j = 1. Unless I am wrong, the case statement will never produce anything but default, and after the i = 2 iteration of the loop, j will just end up being j = 3 - i(2) which is 1. Am I overthinking this?

Comment: Do you have to use switch statement?

Comment: No. I can remove it as well.

Comment: you could just `j= 1;` and be done with it. And maybe that is the _trick_ in the question.

Comment: Since the values and computation steps are all deterministic and known, you can just run it to check the final values and replace this code with simple assignments, making this a silly assignment.

Comment: This is for a college senior level course. I feel like this is a bit below me, which is why I am thinking I am overthinking it. I ran through all iterations and came up with the j == 1 as I stated above. I think the purpose of the question is to make sure we know how to write structured code, but I think it is a stupid question.

Comment: @Nick what course is this?

Comment: @GRC A course entitled Structures of Programming Languages.

Comment: I don't think you are overthinking it, your analysis was correct.

Comment: Wouldn't it be true that the code produces two outputs, not one? i=3 and j=1?

Comment: @jeff6times7 there is no output to the code. The only variable ever set within the loop is j, and i is just used for the for loop... after the loop runs, i would be 3, you are correct.

Comment: I meant outcome. I assumed that since you and I both used the word "produce" that my meaning would be understood. The side effect of running the code is i=3 and j=1. If you hand in code that reads j=1, then you might not get an A or you would get extra credit if you showed that you better understand the greater effect of executing the code.

Comment: Note that the final value of `i` is also part of the  observable behaviour

Comment: @Nick what book are you using?

Comment: @GRC Concepts of Programming Languages 11th edition. The question comes from chapter 8, I believe, in the programming exercises.

Comment: @Nick https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwiSnO-nrNTZAhWRylkKHVaSAq4QFghFMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emu.edu.tr%2Faelci%2Fcourses%2Fd-318%2F2005-spring%2Fanswerstoselectedproblems.doc&usg=AOvVaw2mhgHgH628gpYp7ueKMRmh we were all overthinking it :)

Comment: @GRC For anyone who is curious about it, to find the "answer" in that doc you linked, search the Word document for `j = -3;`. However, that answer _does_ use a `break` statement, and it also is a similar but not identical problem. But just like this problem, there is no need for a loop at all! The lengthy and convoluted answer in the Word doc is equivalent to `i = 10; j = -6; key = -1;`. No, I didn't figure that out by mentally stepping through the code - I don't have the patience for 10 iterations. I just pasted it into a simple console app and ran it with a breakpoint after the code. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> j will just end up being j = 3 - i(2) which is 1

Correct:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 int i,j;    

 j = -3;
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
    switch (j + 2)
    {  // j = -1 ->

        case 3:
             printf("3\n");
        case 2: j--;
             printf("2\n");
        break;

        case 0: 
        j += 2;
             printf("0\n");
        break;

        default: 
        j = 0;
        printf("j=%d  i=%d  default:\n", j, i);
    }

    if (j > 0){
          printf("j>0\n");       
          break;
    }

    j = 3 - i;
    printf("j=3-i  j=%d i=%d \n", j, i);
  }

  printf("j=%d  i=%d  END\n", j, i);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
j=0  i=0  default:
j=3-i  j=3 i=0 
j=0  i=1  default:
j=3-i  j=2 i=1 
j=0  i=2  default:
j=3-i  j=1 i=2 
j=1  i=3  END
```

Therefore, for the above code, the minimum simplification is:

```
j = 1; 
i = 3;
```

Comment: The code in the question changes both `i` and `j`. This answer shows only `j`.

Comment: "Rewrite it using no goto's or breaks."

Comment: @GRC Thank you for your question. The whole piece of  code produces simple outcome ` j=1;` and `i=3;` My take is that the code fragment can be replaced with those two lines of code.